# How can I disable a com+ application programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, com+

How can I disable a COM+ application programmatically as I would do it in the Component Services snap-in by right-clicking on a COM+ application and selecting disable?

I tried the following code in vb.net but it did not work:

```
Dim obj = New COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
Dim applications = obj.GetCollection("Applications")
applications.Populate()
For i As Integer = 0 To applications.Count - 1
    Dim application = applications.Item(i)
    If application.Name = "MyApplicationName" Then
            application.Value("IsEnabled") = False
    End If
Next
```

The .NET code disabling a COM+ application would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to save the changes, that means, at the end I added the statement:

```
applications.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: I recently faced this problem, so i wrote the below article: http://www.prashant-kumar.in/how-to-start-and-stop-a-com-application-using-c-sharp/